# angularjs2: initialize services with http response

Tags: angular

We've been reading some resources for hours, but can't seem to find the right thing. It might be easy, but we can't seem to find a good way: how should we initialize multiple services, if possible at app boot time, with configuration data that we fetch from a server?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this I believe would be to inject each of the services you wish to instantiate at boot into your primary app component, then call a public method on each of perhaps `getConfig` within the app components constructor method.

```
// app.component
constructor(serviceName1:ServiceName1, serviceName2:ServiceName2) {
    serviceName1.getConfig();
    serviceName2.getConfig();
}
```

Then on each service, perform the request to get the configuration data and set up your service as needed.

```
// serviceName1.component
getConfig() {
    // Perform request and get config variable
    this.config = config;
}
```